# Is there a way to do a 3D map only with a 2D Lidar and IMU sensor in ros2?

Tags: slam, mapping, imu, 2dlidar, 3d-reconstruction

I'm working in ros2 humble with a 2D lidar and an IMU sensor and I'm willing to do a 3D mapping with this things. I have already done a 2D mapping using RF2O pkg (that gives me an odometry only with the 2D Lidar) and using slam_toolbox for the mapping. But now I want to add an IMU sensor for doing a 3D mapping,

Is there a pkg that can help me doing that?

Comment: Is your 2D lidar mounted in a way you can obtain 3D data (e.g. not just mounted horizontally)?

Comment: My idea is to use it as handheld sensor. The idea is not to tilt it a lot, it is for doing 2D mapping and detecting when is tilt to do the projection to the XY plane. Hope you can understand my idea.

Comment: Also, I was looking for doing visual odometry in ros2 and I didn't find so much. Do you know if there is some pkg or solution for this? (To do odometry for mapping without knowing anything about the surroundings)

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is externally rotating the lidar but I don't recommand it. See the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ezyhTAEyHs

Just using a low cost 3D lidar like mid-360 is much more beneficial than making such a complicated system. The solution above was needed when even 2D lidar was over 20k. Mid-360 is just 800 bucks now.

And even if you were able to make 3D scanner using IMU+2D configuration, your system won't be able to stop moving even for a second due to the observability problem.